# Automatic display of WebP images instead of JPG images via Htaccess

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, mod-headers

I use Wordpress, the plugin "EWWW Image Optimizer" creates from JPG images automatically also WebP versions (example: From the image image.jpg is also an image image.jpg.webp created). The plugin also writes (successfully) an entry in the Htaccess, which should cause that instead of JPG images the WebP versions are displayed in the browser. According to the test of EWWW Image Optimizer the entry should apparently work (for this the plugin shows a green graphic with "WebP"). But when I open the page, only JPG versions are displayed everywhere. I check this e.g. in Chrome with the extension "View Image Info (properties)" and also in the Console at the "Type" of the image. Everywhere it says JPG, not WebP. I do NOT use Nginx cache, in my case I always see the uncached versions in the frontend. According to PHPinfo, the mod_headers module is also active on Apache.

Alternatively, I can deliver WebP via the plugin "JS WebP Rewriting" or "Picture WebP Rewriting" - that also works, but only partially (for example, it does not work if you click on an image, it opens large in a gallery, then it still shows JPG).

The Htaccess variant is the best variant, because it should be ensured that automatically existing WebP images are displayed.

I have researched and unfortunately have not found a solution. I do not know why it does not work, do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you using Nginx ase your web server?

Comment: No, it's an Apache server....

Comment: Where in the `.htaccess` file did that block get added? Is it before or after the WordPress front controller rules?

Comment: At the very end of the .htaccess file. However, I have also tried manually placing the code at the top.

Comment: Is the .htaccess file active in general?  If you create a syntax error in it, does the website return a 500 internal server error?

Comment: Have you verified that you have both mod_rewrite and mod_headers installed on your server?

Comment: Yes, the htaccess is active, I have been running the website for years. mod_rewrite and mod_headers are both active. If I put an error in the htaccess, so it comes to a server error.

Comment: Can you test with `curl` on the command line.  Craft an Accept header like your rule is expecting and request an image and see what content type is served?  `curl --head -H 'Accept:image/webp' https://example.com/image.jpg`

Comment: Which command line? I use a shared server, I have never used curl.

Comment: Can I use Windows PowerShell for curl?

Comment: Yes, curl runs on many platforms, you can download it for Windows: https://curl.se

Comment: The website claims Curl is automatically included in Windows 10 (from version 1804). How do I run it under Windows 10? I have tried it via PowerShell, there are generally only error messages with Curl. Even if I only try "curl --head http://www.google.com/".

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: If you tell me the actual you are all of one of the images I can help you test it with curl

Comment: Hm, I do not want to publish my domain here. Because otherwise it would point to me as a private person.

Comment: "I do NOT use Nginx cache" - Why do you mention Nginx at all? If there is a front-end (Nginx) proxy that serves your static resources (not uncommon on shared servers) then if the original `.jpg` file exists, that file will be served, bypassing your rule in `.htaccess`. You should be able to determine whether this is the case by examining the HTTP response headers in the browser dev tools - look for a `Server` (or other distinguishing) header.

Comment: @MrWhite I mention NGINX because I was immediately asked about it in relation to this problem (not here in the forum) and because my web host allows to enable Nginx manually (but I didn't enable it, it's disabled). What exactly should I look for in the Chrome Console? I open the page (in logged in state, thereby also not cached by W3 Total Cache), open the console and then...? PS: In the "network"-tab of the console in the header it says "Server: Apache" (because it is an Apache Server".

Comment: "Server: Apache" - That looks like the response is coming from Aapche (not some Nginx proxy) - which is good.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you are using (including your complete `.htaccess` file - in case there might be conflicts) _and_ the URL(s) you are requesting and the expected response. There might be a simple error with the script, or we may just end up suggesting something very similar, which isn't going to be helpful.